# How to process checkout on secure subdomain like secure.doamin.com in magento

Tags: magento

we have store in magento and it working fine we want to checkout of oder on sub domain secure.domain.com instead of same site so please tell me the steps how to achieve this functionality . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a secure subdomain i.e. secure.domain.com , i assume you have created another website in magento admin.

What is required is that in admin

`System > Configuration > Web>Session Cookie Management > Cookie Domain`
 add for that particular website domain as domain.com.

Check this link for more info, 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/web

Let me know if it works!